# MVC 3 exclude fields from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql

How can i create a model and exclude a few fields from being in the database. I have a **user model** which new users can put information in but then i want to add a few more strings to the **user model** so i can have email fields there too but offcourse i don't want to save those email fields to the database.
  something like this ##`public class user { 
            public string user  {}
            public string email {} --exclude the email portion from being in database.

}`.##
I have tried doing 2 separate models and putting them into a parentview class but I kept getting an ID error since the parent class has no ID and i dont want to save the email fields in database... any suggestions

Comment: Are you using Entitiy framework or nhibernate?

Comment: I am using the Entity framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a partial class User with your custom fields

```
public partial class User
{
    public string Email
    {
        set; get;
    }
}
```

You can check this tutorial for more informations:  [NerdDinner Step 3: Building the Model](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part3.htm)

Comment: Did this help, or it's not really what you're looking for?